# C# WPF set system color to button

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to change the background color of button to system color. Just like I am changing the button color

```
button2.Background = Brushes.Blue;
```

to blue. But no I want to Change the color to system color.

Comment: There are a lot of different system colors. Which one do you want?

Answer (score 2):

You can get system color from System.Windows.SystemColors

```
button2.Background = System.Windows.SystemColors.MenuHighlightBrush;
```

WPF Background is of type System.Windows.Media.Brush. You can set another color like this:

```
// using System.Windows.Media;

button2.Background = Brushes.White;

button2.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.White);

button2.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I Hope this helps

```
<Button 
      Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.DesktopBrushKey}}" 
      Content="Hello, World!" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
button2.Background = SystemColors.ActiveCaptionBrush;
```

SystemColors belong to the System.Windows namespace.

Comment: It is not giving the actual system color. I want it to pick from theme

Answer (score 0):

Background is of type Brush. But you can create a solid brush out of the system color and use that.

```
SolidBrush systemColorBrush = new SolidBrush(systemColor); // Create SolidBrush from color
button2.Background = systemColorBrush;
```

Comment: solidbrush gives me error in WPF, But it works perfectly in Windows Form.