# WPF set Textbox Border color from C# code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application in which I have to make several updates.

One of the updates is that I'm changing from a **Label** to a **TextBox**

I see in many examples of Textbox border color getting set from **XAML** , that is NOT going to work for me as there are Business rule conditions to have a Red or Black

I have tried:

```
lblValidMsg.BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;
lblValidMsg.BorderBrush = System.Drawing.Color.Red;     // converter.ConvertFromString("#FF0000"); //borderColor;


lblValidMsg.BorderBrush = SystemColors.Control;

private Color borderColor = Color.Gray;
```

I'm sure that it is "simple" but the constant different errors are like

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Color' to 'System.Windows.Media.Brush'
```

YES I am aware that I left the textbox name as the label name hence the starting with "lbl"

Update:

I see that people set the background and foreground, but that is not way i need to do

```
textBox1.Background = Brushes.Blue;
textBox1.Foreground = Brushes.Yellow;
```

I did try

```
lblValidMsg.BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;
```

That gives   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Color' to 'System.Windows.Media.Brush'

Comment: May help [Set system color to button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28722540/2122718]) or
 [Set background color of Textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/979906/2122718)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
textBox.BorderBrush = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
```

Works for me, make sure you're not using the System.Drawing.Brushes, you need to use the Windows.Media brush instead.

Comment: Yes that works , the message I guess was obvious sort of, but you did it!  thx!